# How can I compare dates from a JSON object with dates in "5/17/16" format using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm making a task management widget that displays tasks based on if they are in the current day, week or month. I'd like to push dates into weeklyTaskArray, dailyTaskArray, monthlyTaskArray and render them using .length.

This is what I've tried and the "if" statement runs but pushes all data into dailyQuoteArray/weeklyQuoteArray etc:

```
        $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/quotes.json',
        responseType: "json"
    }).then(function(response) {
        let quotes = response.data;
        angular.copy(quotes, quoteArray)

        quotes.forEach(function (element) {
          let currentDate = element.expiration_date;
          console.log(currentDate);
          var moment = require('moment')
          var todaysDate = moment("05/17/2016");
          var date2 = moment(currentDate)
          var answer = moment(todaysDate).diff(date2, "days")
          console.log("this is the answer", answer);

          if (answer >= 2) {
            dailyQuoteArray.push(answer)
          }
          if (answer <= 7) {
            weeklyQuoteArray.push(answer)
            console.log("weeklyquotear length", weeklyQuoteArray.length);
          }

        })
    });
```

Comment: Can you change the json endpoint to return ISO dates, such as `"2016-08-24T18:47:17.000Z"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your expression to javascript date object. You can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) for date operations like converting or comparing.

```
var date = moment("05/17/2017", "DD/MM/YYYY")._d;
```

Comment: Thanks @scokmen I have code         var moment = require('moment')
        
     var todaysDate = moment()
     var date2 = moment().add(5, 'days')
     var answer = moment(todaysDate).diff(date2, "days")
    
     console.log("this is the answer",answer);

Comment: Thanks again. I've just updated the code. Having a lot of trouble pushing into separate arrays based on week,day,month

Answer (score 0):

Use [´date.parse()´](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to create a JavaScript Date

```
new Date("05/17/2017"); //Wed May 17 2017 00:00:00
```

Comment: @SalmanA Would you mind to share your awsome knowledge with us?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of Date.parse yourself, especially the second paragraph, and the part which reads _**dateString** A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected)._